# Concurrency when writing to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, io

I'm working on a p2p filesharing system in python3 right now and I've come across an issue I don't know how to fix exactly.

I have peers with a server process and a client process where a client process connects to the other nodes, puts it in its own thread, and listens for data over a socket. When downloading from only one other peer, the file is written correctly with no problem, but when it is split up over multiple peers, the file is corrupted. The data is correctly received from both other peers so I'm thinking this would be a file write issue.

When I get the data from a peer, I open the file, seek to the position where the data comes from, and then write it and close the file. Would locks be the solution to this?

This is the code that is in its own thread that is constantly listening

```
def handleResponse(clientConnection, fileName, fileSize):
    # Listen for connections forever
    try:
        while True:
            #fileName = ""
            startPos = 0
            data = clientConnection.recv(2154)
            # If a response, process it
            if (len(data) > 0):
                split = data.split(b"\r\n\r\n")
                #print(split[0])
                headers = split[0].replace(b'\r\n', b' ').split(b' ')
                # Go through the split headers and grab the startPos and fileName
                for i in range(len(headers)):
                    if (headers[i] == b"Range:"):
                        startPos = int(headers[i+1])
                        #fileName = headers[i+2].decode()
                        break
                # Write the file at the seek pos
                mode = "ab+"
                if (startPos == 0):
                    mode = "wb+"
                with open ("Download/" + fileName, mode) as f:
                    f.seek(startPos, 0)
                    f.write(split[1])
                    f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you open the file in append mode? From [the documentation of open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): *"... 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems, means that __all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position)__..."*.

Comment: I didn't know that (on MacOS). Is this what is corrupting my file where multiple threads are writing data out of order? That would make sense if it were the case.

Comment: I can actually see no reason to open the file with append in the first place, no matter if concurrent access or not. You should open for writing (not appending) and you just seek to the position you want, no matter what the position is.

Comment: Yeah, Since w overwrites the file if it exists, I'm gonna have to read the initial contents of the file, insert the data into the correct position and then write the entire block. Correct me if I'm going in the wrong direction, but I think I'm on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, r+ can do what I need it to, I just need to create the file before writing or else it fails. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Steffen Ullrich.

Solution is to open the file in rb+ instead of ab+, seek to the position and write. Do note that if the file does not exist, it will throw an exception since it is not created in rb+